# Updating from NVIDIA driver 352 to 375 removed the top and side panel bars

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I tried reverting back to version 352, but it will automatically install version 375 instead. I also tried versions 361, 367 from the "additional-drivers" panel, as well as the Nouveau driver, but none solved the problem.

Is there anything I can do to avoid a fresh Ubuntu install?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I have 4 Titan-X GPUs.